# CSS font size for mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, web, responsive-design

I have simple pages completed that seem to respond well to different size screens. I haven't done anything fancy to achieve this - just avoided fixed sizes etc.

One page, however, has a large single word in a large font:

[image]

When I resize the browser, all other content lays out correctly, but the title word of course won't break:

[image]

What is the correct way to handle this? Is there some way to adjust the font size based on the screen width?

Comment: You should take a look at [mediaqueries](http://mediaqueri.es/). You can set mediaquery for mobile layout (a certain break point) and can change font-size.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use media queries like:

```
@media all and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px), (min-width: 1151px) {
   body {
    background: #ccc;
  }
}
```

Some more info can be found here: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Answer (score 12):

Another option is to use [viewport-percentage lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths).

> **vw unit:** Equal to 1% of the width of the initial containing block.

You can read more about it on [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) which discusses a repaint bug for certain browsers, but you can fix it with a little jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/7L9QH/

#### CSS

```
h1 {
    font-size: 25vw;
}
```

Comment: vh would work better because its huge difference between vw of desktop and mobile

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [FitText](http://fittextjs.com/)?

It is a jQuery plugin made for that occasions. Quoting their description:

> FitText makes font-sizes flexible. Use this plugin on your fluid or responsive layout to achieve scalable headlines that fill the width of a parent element.